# (SQL) Select SUM of (Column 1) * Min(Column2) Where Column 1 and 2 share an ID

Tags: sql, join, view, min

I am quite new to SQL, so this query has been giving me a headache. For reference, I have two tables (*Simplified versions*):

```
CREATE TABLE PARTS_USED
(  
    Part INT NOT NULL,
    Product INT NOT NULL,
    Quantity INT
    PRIMARY KEY(Part, Product)
);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE SUPPLY
(
    Vendor INT NOT NULL,
    Part INT NOT NULL,
    Price DECIMAL(8,2) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(Vendor, Part),
);
```

`Product` and `Part` are both unique IDs.

What I am trying to do here is get the Total "Cost" (sum of (`Quantity * (Minimum Part Price)`)) of each product.

So far, I have this query:

```
CREATE VIEW PRODUCT_COST(ProductID, TotalCost)
AS 
    SELECT 
        PARTS_USED.Product, 
        SUM(PARTS_USED.Quantity * (SUPPLY.Price))
    FROM 
        PARTS_USED
    INNER JOIN 
        SUPPLY ON PARTS_USED.Part = SUPPLY.Part
    GROUP BY 
        PARTS_USED.Product;
```

However, I'm getting the `MIN(SUPPLY.Price)` is proving to be difficult; I want to be able to just change `SUPPLY.Price` in the `SELECT` line to `MIN(SUPPLY.Price)`, but this does not work. With the way the tables are set up, I am quite lost as to how I should be using JOIN.

Answer (score 1):

Because multiplication is commutative, you might be able to just take the product of the sum of quantity and the minimum price:

```sql
CREATE VIEW PRODUCT_COST(ProductID, TotalCost) AS
SELECT pu.Product, SUM(pu.Quantity) * MIN(s.Price) AS "Total Cost"
FROM PARTS_USED pu
INNER JOIN SUPPLY s ON s.Part = pu.Part
GROUP BY pu.Product;
```